# Prolog Simplification

Tags: prolog

Could anyone tell me if there is a simpler way to write this code in Prolog, I need to have this narrowed down to make it more compact.

This is what I have so far:

```
add(X,[],[X]).
add(X,[A|L],[A|L1]) :-
    add(X,L,L1).

head([X|_], X).

exist(X,Y,A,B) :-
    between(1, 8, X),
    between(1, 8, Y),
    between(1,8,A),
    between(1, 8, B).

exist(X/Y, A/B) :-
    exist(X,Y,A,B).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete `head/2`. Prolog's pattern matching is shorter and more readable than this.

Second, what are you trying to do with `add/3`? It looks to me like all it will do is give you the last element of the second list if they happen to have exactly the same elements except the second one having one more. In other words, the only successful unifications look like `add(Z, [A,B,...,Y], [A,B...Y,Z])` and I'm straining to imagine a scenario you might need that.

In `exist/4` fix the spacing on line 3! Have some pride in your work! `exist/4` will generate you all permutations of 4 variables selecting from 1-8. Looks fine, not sure why you need it.

`exist/2` just reformats `exist/4` so that it looks like fractions. Again, not sure why you need it.

What are you trying to do with this code? This looks like a strange and unrelated pile of utilities.

Comment: This is part of a bigger program which finds the shortest path for a knight on a chess board. And I need to make the code above more concise and less messy before I submit my assignment. Is there any way I could show you what I have so far and you could guide me how to improve it privately. Thanks!

ps. I fixed the spacing in my work just posted this before I did...

Comment: @zarrexx if you only ever use `exist/2`, move the body of `exist/4` in there and delete `exist/4` too.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I could send you my full code and you could help me out? Because I cant post my full code here